# cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats source code

Tags: python, opencv

Does anyone knows where to find the source code for cv2.connectedComponentWithStats?
I would like to see exactly what's happening in this function to help me understand better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/13a995cc1d2700812dfd979097924703ba2267bc/modules/imgproc/src/connectedcomponents.cpp#L5752-L5769) in C++. The Python package calls the compiled C++ code.